# Installing 'tm' package and getting a warning

Tags: r, tm

I'm starting to learn R and text mining capabilities. Lately when I have been using `install.packages('tm')`, I get this error

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘\\HKDC01\Folder Redirection\myname\Documents\R\R-3.2.3\library\file1c1427307792\tm’ to ‘\\HKDC01\Folder Redirection\myname\Documents\R\R-3.2.3\library\tm’
```

The downloaded binary packages are in

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsRcIY8\downloaded_packages
```

And when I call `library(tm)`, I get an error as it hasn't been installed properly.

Comment: Do you have adequate permissions for that location?